# Group Policy Setting for Office Shared Path not applying to sub-OU correctly

Tags: windows, group-policy, office-2010

I'm trying to set a different 'Workgroup templates path' for a set of users, along with a few other minor settings.

We have a policy ("Global MSO") with all office settings that sits at the top of the domain, and sets a path Y:\Templates

Due to a merge we now have users in another OU we would like to set Z:\Templates for this shared path. We call the policy "Merged MSO"

Now as I understand it the policy with a higher priority when looking in the 'Group Policy Inheritance' tab should be applied last. And correctly the policy for "Merged MSO" is number 1, and "Global MSO" is 5th.

- Neither policy has enforced set
- Neither policy has loopback processing
- Both policies are enabled for both User/Computer settings
- Both are enabled
- Both have 'Authenticated Users' in security filtering
- Neither have a WMI Filter
- The settings are user settings, and are applied at the User OU

Now in GP Results I can see *some* of the "Merged MSO" settings are applied, but only where the "Global MSO" Policy has no setting at all
* If I enforce "Merged MSO" there is no change in what is applied

On inspecting via the RSoP add-in I see the Global MSO gets applied twice (along with a few other policies), with the "Merged MSO" being applied in the middle - what could be the explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a rogue policy which had loopback processing on 'replace'

This of course means that all policies are applied twice - once in the user context, once in the computer context, regardless of whether or not the they are user/computer based.

The policy at domain level wins because it applies to the computer, which applies after the user policy. So the order seems to be:

Local Policy
Global (applied to User)
Merged (applied to User, as it is only linked to User OU) 
Global (applied to Computer)

I suspect if I applied the Merged policy to the computer OU it would apply last